# Best solution to import and update millions of records every day on Heroku

Tags: ruby, postgresql, heroku

I have to execute some rake tasks which import and update millions of products each day with data coming from CSV files. I currently use Heroku Scheduler to run rake tasks but I found that is doesn't work properly. I have one task which import data, and then another task that update data.

My two issues are:

- My rake task is crashing sometimes so it fails to import all data, I tried using begin and rescue for each sensitive parts of the code but it doesn't seem to do the job.
- The other issue is that the import task is run every day at 2 am and the update at 9 am. But sometimes the import task is not yet finished at 9am so the update task is never run.

What resource should I be using to do all of this big data stuff on Heroku? Maybe another solution such as Amazon AWS or Google Cloud would be more adapted?

Comment: Show those rake tasks, please. (the essential parts)

Comment: You could fix the "crashes sometimes" and wait with the second task until the first is done. There is not much more to say with the little information we have.

Answer (score 1):

My first idea would be to import the CSV into a temp table in the database without any change or data transformation. That should be pretty fast with pure SQL.

Then I would create one background job for each line in the temp table (for example with Sidekiq). And each of those jobs should only import that specific line.

Running multiple background jobs in parallel should speed up the process significantly. Plus when one line raises an error and cannot be imported then other jobs are not affected and the background job queue then shows you exactly which job and therefore which line could not be imported and why.

Comment: do you have a ressource or a tutorial to do that ?

Comment: @user3805610 Sidekiq Pro's [Batches](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches) feature sounds like a good fit. The docs show a basic example for importing the rows of an Excel file in parallel. Each row is processed a separate job and the batch tracks the progress as a whole.